# Best way to hide titlebar / actionbar?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I want to hide the titlebar (actionbar) when in landscape mode, so I use this code:

```
if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
           requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        }
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_entries);
```

This works on most devices, but it crashes the app on HTC Sensation XL (http://www.gsmarena.com/htc_sensation_xl-4161.php).

This is the style.xml (I'm using the CustomActionBarTheme in the manifest):

```
<style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
           parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
        <item name="android:dropDownSpinnerStyle">@style/SpinnerAppTheme</item>
        <item name="android:editTextBackground">@drawable/apptheme_edit_text_holo_light</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyActionBar"
           parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="android:background">@color/orange</item>
        <item name="android:icon">@drawable/ic_action_logo</item>
    </style>
```

This is the crash log :

```
03-24 14:51:39.129 E/AndroidRuntime(13890): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-24 14:51:39.129 E/AndroidRuntime(13890): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.myprojects.tib.abstimetracker/com.myprojects.tib.abstimetracker.activities.ViewEntries}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-24 14:51:39.129 E/AndroidRuntime(13890):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2194)
03-24 14:51:39.129 E/AndroidRuntime(13890):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2229)
03-24 14:51:39.129 E/AndroidRuntime(13890):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3791)
03-24 14:51:39.129 E/AndroidRuntime(13890):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:139)
03-24 14:51:39.129 E/AndroidRuntime(13890):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1265)
03-24 14:51:39.129 E/AndroidRuntime(13890):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-24 14:51:39.129 E/AndroidRuntime(13890):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
03-24 14:51:39.129 E/AndroidRuntime(13890):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4945)
03-24 14:51:39.129 E/AndroidRuntime(13890):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-24 14:51:39.129 E/AndroidRuntime(13890):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-24 14:51:39.129 E/AndroidRuntime(13890):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
03-24 14:51:39.129 E/AndroidRuntime(13890):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
03-24 14:51:39.129 E/AndroidRuntime(13890):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-24 14:51:39.129 E/AndroidRuntime(13890): Caused by: **java.lang.NullPointerException**
03-24 14:51:39.129 E/AndroidRuntime(13890):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$PanelFeatureState.onRestoreInstanceState(PhoneWindow.java:3493)
03-24 14:51:39.129 E/AndroidRuntime(13890):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.restorePanelState(PhoneWindow.java:1733)
03-24 14:51:39.129 E/AndroidRuntime(13890):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.restoreHierarchyState(PhoneWindow.java:1689)
03-24 14:51:39.129 E/AndroidRuntime(13890):     at android.app.Activity.onRestoreInstanceState(Activity.java:939)
03-24 14:51:39.129 E/AndroidRuntime(13890):     at android.app.Activity.performRestoreInstanceState(Activity.java:911)
03-24 14:51:39.129 E/AndroidRuntime(13890):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnRestoreInstanceState(Instrumentation.java:1132)
03-24 14:51:39.129 E/AndroidRuntime(13890):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2172)
03-24 14:51:39.129 E/AndroidRuntime(13890):     ... 12 more
```

My question is : can anyone tell me what should I check for null and also what is the difference between a titlebar and an actionbar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Title bar is a small part of the UI that you can supply with some text and a color. You see it on a lot of Android 2.0 Apps. See https://androidproblem.wordpress.com/category/title-bar/

The Actionbar is the bar with buttons that has back navigation etc. If you can chose, you use it instead of the Titlebar. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html

to check for null values you can find which  line is giving you a null pointer exception and then you can add an if check as shown below:

```
if ( x != null){

//perform actual action

}

else {

// Display a toast or some thing and perform a graceful exit from the application or stay in the application.

}
```

Hope this helps. The difference is based on a previous SO answer.

Comment: Thank you, the links were very instructive. I think I'll try ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
            if (bar != null)
            bar.hide();